# Overview of nonlinear analysis, differential equations (ODE and PDE), dynamical systems, and mathematical physics, and their relationships

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics

The fields of **(i)** *nonlinear analysis*, **(ii)** *ODE* and *PDE*, **(iii)** *dynamical systems*, and **(iv)** *mathematical physics* (e.g., electromagnetism, general relativity, gravitation, etc,...) are very huge, fertile, and, in a sense, unorganized  (see, for example, *[Open problems in PDEs, dynamical systems, mathematical physics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125049/open-problems-in-pdes-dynamical-systems-mathematical-physics)* on *MathOverflow*).

Yet, they seem to me extremely interconnected; however, it seems also difficult to grasp a general (more or less) precise idea of their **relationships** (**i.e.**: the *differences* among their *aims*, and among the *topics*, *problems*, *ideas*, *methods*, etc. that they study).

Apparently, prof. S. Klainerman, in his survey paper *[PDE as a Unified Subject](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~seri/homepage/papers/telaviv.pdf)*, gives a somewhat clear picture of "the area of PDE". This leads me to the following question:

> **Question:**
>
> > Can you point out some (several) *survey papers* (somewhat *in the spirit of Klainerman's*) that offer a clear precise <sup>* (as much as possible)</sup>  **overview** of the areas **(i)**, **(ii)**, **(iii)**, **(iv)** with their problems and their key ideas, and possibly highlight their mutual *relationships*, the *history* of their developement and their relevance in mathematics (and also in science)?

Comment: Simply too broad a question. I've been working in these areas for more than 30 years and still have no "clear precise overview". Glad that I've been able to solve some very specific problems there. And that's it.

Comment: Within the realm of applications, Non-linear analysis looks at phenomena that don't have simple trivial descriptions. ODEs describe objects in a system. PDEs describe entire systems. Dynamical Systems shows perturbations in a system or to an object in a system can result in different futures *not* linear to the size of perturbation. Mathematical Physics attempts to justify already developed physics in "rigorous" ways. For instance, the renormalization "fiasco" stems directly from pertubative analysis.

Comment: Maybe you know this, but ODEs and PDEs can be unified in a very simple way, namely by viewing considering ODEs over arbitrary Banach spaces, and seeing PDEs as these, when the Banach space is a certain function space (or even seeing a PDE as just a linear equation in Banach Spaces). This is useful, at least, for highlighting the principle difficulty of finding general PDE theorems, that infinite dimensional topology is radically different from that of finite dimension. A lot of the times this even inspires methods in PDEs (at least, my course was motivated this way).

Comment: Dear @HandeBruijn, any survey paper which gives *some kind* of overview will be helpful.

Comment: @Zach466920: There are _several_ renormalization fiascos in physics; some of them stem directly from the idea that Coulomb's law remains valid for infinitely small distances.

Comment: @GPerez: It remains to be seen if Banach spaces offer so much additional value when solving practical problems. I could easily do without them.

Comment: @HandeBruijn duly noted, didn't know there was more than one.

Comment: http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8350.html

Comment: @WillieWong, thanks for the reference. I see that in the Princeton Companion there is another interesting article by prof. Klainerman. How should I narrow down the question in your opinion?

Comment: Can't help you with that. Any narrowing will be a different question from what you have asked, and I can't read your mind (sorry) well enough to guess where you would prefer the emphasis be placed.

Comment: @WillieWong Got it. Anyway, if you feel like giving a try, I don't mind (even if the question ends up slightly different) :).